# Every elementary abelian $p$-group of $G$ consists of semisimple elements.

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ a simple (exceptional) algebraic group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic not $p$.

Then every elementary abelian $p$-group of $G$ consists of semisimple elements.

Sorry I am being stupid here. But why? Just because it is commutative? Thx.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried: every semisimple element lies in some maximal torus in $G^o$. But apparently there are nontoral elementary abelian groups, so I got a contradiction!